# How to debug the an signatures do not match the previously installed version error

Tags: android, adb, android-signing

For the new application the build system has been updated and now the `adb install -r` is failing with

```
adb: failed to install … : Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE: Package … signatures do not match the previously installed version; ignoring!]
```

The usual quick fix for this is to just deinstall but I am currently testing the update process of my application so **deinstall is not an option**. I have to get it working without hiccup.

How do you debug the signature process? Is there a log output to activate so I see which key is used? Can I see which key used by examining the apk file?

PS: Similar question have been asked but they are answered with “just deinstall” — but as I said: **deinstall is not an option**.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use the `--debug` option to get more information
2. Check for the `signing-config.json` file and check if the correct parameter are used.